# Increasing maximum execution time

Tags: php

My code reads from xml file and saves data in mysql database. Through the code it iterates around 8000 times. In the localhost i added the following code in index.php:

```
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 8000);
    ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

But its not working in the server. What should i do to make it working in the server?

Comment: What exactly is not working? How is it failing?

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` is better than `ini_set('max_execution_time');` for allowing infinite run time. I seriously doubt (and hope you don't) need 512Mb memory for this, if you do you should probably look at optimising your code to regularly destroy large data stores, e.g. with `unset()`

Answer (score 2):

Try `set_time_limit(0)` that will set it to infinite.

Comment: Not so much set it to infinite as remove the time limit entirely. If the code is being requested via the web browser, you also have to worry about timeout issues. If this is the case, take a look at [ignore_user_abort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)